Props not available in UI when typing imported from another file
I just initiated a project with storybook (v8.2.7) and i noticed the props don't appear in the UI when the TS types are imported from another file.
All props visible in UI:
type Props = {
  name: string
}

export function HelloWorld(props: Props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <MyComponent {...props} />
    </div>
  );
}

Any props visible in UI:
import { type Props } from "types/props"

export function HelloWorld(props: Props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <MyComponent {...props} />
    </div>
  );
}

This is not an import issue, vscode shows me the type but as an "alias"), so it looks like storybook is not able to parse the props when they are themself imported from another file.
Is there a way to fix this?
